# How to check which symbols on my shared library have non-position independent code (PIC)?

Tags: linux, gcc, debian, powerpc

I'm trying to build a .deb package with `debuild  -i -us -uc -b` and in the end I see:

```
Now running lintian...
warning: the authors of lintian do not recommend running it with root     privileges!
W: libluajit-5.1-2: hardening-no-relro usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libluajit-5.1.so.2.1.0
E: libluajit-5.1-2: shlib-with-non-pic-code usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libluajit-5.1.so.2.1.0
W: luajit: hardening-no-relro usr/bin/luajit-2.1.0-alpha
W: luajit: binary-without-manpage usr/bin/luajit-2.1.0-alpha
Finished running lintian.
```

I have a hunch that I failed to define a "PIC code setup", which must be at the beginning of each external function:

```
The following code might appear in a PIC code setup sequence to compute
the distance from a function entry point to the TOC base:
addis 2,12,.TOC.-func@ha
addi 2,2,.TOC.-func@l
```

as specified by the [ABI](http://openpowerfoundation.org/technical/technical-resources/technical-specifications/), page 99.

However I couldn't find the symbols which were non-PIC. Or maybe some relevant file that was not compiled with `-fPIC`?

**Info:**

system architecture: ppc64le

compiling .so library with: gcc -shared -fPIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find which symbols made your elf non-PIC/PIE (Position Independent Code/Executable), use `scanelf` from `pax-utils` package (on ubuntu, install it with `sudo apt-get install pax-utils`):

```
$ scanelf -qT /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2.1.0 | head -n 3
  libluajit-5.1.so.2.1.0: buf_grow [0x7694] in (optimized out: previous lj_BC_MODVN) [0x7600]
  libluajit-5.1.so.2.1.0: buf_grow [0x769C] in (optimized out: previous lj_BC_MODVN) [0x7600]
  libluajit-5.1.so.2.1.0: buf_grow [0x76A0] in (optimized out: previous lj_BC_MODVN) [0x7600]
$ objdump -Sa /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2.1.0 | grep -A5 \ 7694:
    7694:       00 00 80 39     li      r12,0
    7698:       c6 07 8c 79     rldicr  r12,r12,32,31
    769c:       00 00 8c 65     oris    r12,r12,0
    76a0:       00 00 8c 61     ori     r12,r12,0
    76a4:       a6 03 89 7d     mtctr   r12
    76a8:       21 04 80 4e     bctrl
```

On my case an absolute address was meant to be load on `r12`, but that's not possible for a dynamic library, so the linker used `0` for that parameter (I had to use `@GOT` operator, but that's the particular solution to my case).

On the `luajit` program, it's possible to define the address on linking time and it looks like this:

```
    1003d0d4:   00 00 80 39     li      r12,0
    1003d0d8:   c6 07 8c 79     rldicr  r12,r12,32,31
    1003d0dc:   07 10 8c 65     oris    r12,r12,4103
    1003d0e0:   30 ca 8c 61     ori     r12,r12,51760
    1003d0e4:   a6 03 89 7d     mtctr   r12
```

Quite different right?

a much detailed explanation can be found on this wonderful [Gentoo wiki page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Textrels_Guide#Introduction).

Answer (score 1):

The failing lintian check is this:

```
        # Now that we're sure this is really a shared library, report on
        # non-PIC problems.
        if ($objdump->{$cur_file}->{TEXTREL}) {
            tag 'shlib-with-non-pic-code', $cur_file;
        }
```

So you can probably find the offending file by looking for a `.o` that contains a `TEXTREL` dynamic section (which is making its way into your final link).

To do this, you can use `readelf --dyanamic`, in something like the following:

```
find . -name '*.o' |
while read obj
do
    if readelf --dynamic "$obj" | grep -q TEXTREL
    then
        echo "$obj contains a TEXTREL section"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @JeremyKerr, but actually no `.o` file has TEXTREL section, only my `.so` file. I'll check now what caused this section to be added if not an object.

Comment: @gut: ah, good to know. Can you post the full final link command too then?

Comment: `gcc   -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libluajit-5.1.so.2   -o libluajit.so lj_vm_dyn.o ljamalg_dyn.o -lm -ldl`

Comment: btw I found nice tricks on [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Textrels_Guide) but none of them were to my case:
`$ scanelf -qT src/libluajit.so
libluajit.so: floor [0x792C] in (optimized out: previous _init) [0x5B50]
...`
And on this [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/5714) the problem persists (bug is still open)

Comment: each of the two objects were compiled like: `gcc -fPIC  -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall   -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE  -DLUA_ROOT=\"/usr\" -DLUA_MULTILIB=\"lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu\" -fno-stack-protector   -c -o ljamalg_dyn.o ljamalg.c
@gcc -fPIC -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -DLUA_ROOT="/usr" -DLUA_MULTILIB="lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu" -fno-stack-protector -c -o ljamalg_dyn.o ljamalg.c`.

Comment: I'd like to try this myself; are you compiling the upstream version of luajit, or something else?

Comment: The official LuaJIT didn't merge the port to PPC64 yet so for the moment you can find it [here](https://github.com/PPC64/LuaJIT-PPC64) and I stored the debian sources for building the package [on my fork, at 'debian-pkg' branch](https://github.com/gut/LuaJIT-PPC64/tree/debian-pkg). Check latest commit for instructions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, if you were also concerned that the lj_vm.o had functions without PIC code setup, I add it everywhere [on a branch](https://github.com/gut/LuaJIT-PPC64/tree/asm-full-of-pic-code-setup) and it didn't solve the issue (actually we already knew that no object had a TEXTREL section)

Comment: **Just figured it out the core of the problem, but I lack deeper knowledge of the ABI to fix it:**
External linkage is the issue. The way I define it work for the linked object but not for the dynamic library: 
e.g: pow on assembly level:
`li 12, pow@higher
sldi 12, 12, 32
oris 12, 12, pow@h
ori 12, 12,  pow@l
mtctr   r12
bctrl`,

pow by disassembling the program `rldicr  r12,r12,32,31
oris    r12,r12,4103
ori     r12,r12,44880
mtctr   r12
bctrl`. The linker filled the values for the program, but he didn't do it for the dynamic library.

Comment: Done! I shouldn't be doing external linkage without @got operator. Please see the latest [commit diff](https://github.com/gut/LuaJIT-PPC64/commit/08ec6ed5dc7e0aac23488935538f02079a4610a0), it'll probably explain it better than I could.

I'll write a proper answer to this hquestion tomorrow. It'll contain the `scanelf -qT` from `pax-utils` package. Thanks a lot that you pointed out the `TEXTREL` issue, that was exactly the point.